# Apollo-Upload-Client doesn't return Id like it states

Tags: reactjs, graphql, apollo

I'm using [apollo-upload-client](https://www.npmjs.com/package/apollo-upload-client), so the call looks like this:

```
const UPLOAD_IMAGE_MUTATION = gql`
mutation AddImageFileMutation ($file: Upload!, $albumId: String!) {
    uploadImage(file: $file, albumId: $albumId){
        id
}}`
```

where you can see that it should return `id`, however I'm finding that is not the case.

My `update:` call shows that `{data}`  contains `{data: {uploadImage: null}}` (see code below for reference). Is there anyway to get it to return the Id?

Update Mutation (using Dropzone for reference)....

```
_onDrop = async (acceptedFiles, rejectedFiles) => {
        acceptedFiles.map((imageFile, index) => {
            const uploadImage = async () => {
                const index = Math.random()
                this.state.loadingBars.push({index: index, preview: imageFile.preview, percentage: 15})
                await this.props.uploadImageMutation({
                    variables: {file: imageFile, albumId: this.state.albumId},
                    update: (store, {data: {uploadImage}}) => {
                        //uploadImage returning null. {data} equals {data: {uploadImage: null}}

                        //stuff
                    }
                })
            };
            uploadImage()
        })
    }
```

Comment: If `uploadImage` is null, it sounds like the resolver for your mutation is either not returning anything, or returning an object not in the expected shape. It might be helpful to see your resolver code.

Comment: you're right, see update

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The resolve code looked like:

```
uploadImage:...
     resolve:...
          const function1()
          const function2()
          const function3()
          function1() //calls function2() and function3()
```

I needed to add **`return function1()`** instead of just calling it

Schema.js file `uploadImage` below for reference if it can help anyone not using `graphql-tools`

```
uploadImage: {
            type: ImageFileType,
            args: {
                albumId: {type: GraphQLString },
                file: {type: ImageScalarType}
            },
            resolve(parentValue, data){
                const storeFS = ({ stream, filename }) => {
                    const id = new ObjectID
                    console.log('added image with ID ', id)
                    const path = `./images/${id}-${filename}`
                    return new Promise((resolve, reject) =>
                        stream
                            .on('error', error => {
                                if (stream.truncated)
                                // Delete the truncated file
                                    fs.unlinkSync(path)
                                reject(error)
                            })
                            .on('end', () => resolve({ id, path }))
                            .pipe(fs.createWriteStream(path))
                    )
                }

                const storeDB = (file, albumId) => {
                    const newImage = new IMAGE({//
                        _id: file.id,
                        name: file.filename,
                        fileType: file.mimetype,
                        url: file.path,
                        albumId: albumId
                    })
                    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
                        //Save image to db
                        newImage.save(function (err, callback) {
                            if (err) reject(err)
                            else {
                                resolve(newImage)
                                return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
                                    //Save image Id to album
                                    ALBUM.findOneAndUpdate(
                                        {"_id": albumId},
                                        {"$addToSet": {images: [callback._id]}},
                                        {"new": true}
                                    ).exec((err, res) => {
                                        if (err) reject(err)
                                        else resolve(res)
                                    })
                                })
                            }
                        })
                    })
                }
                const processUpload = async data => {
                    const { stream, filename, mimetype, encoding } = await data.file //need 0 for array from dropzone
                    const albumId = data.albumId
                    const { id, path } = await storeFS({ stream, filename })
                    return storeDB({ id, filename, mimetype, encoding, path }, albumId)
                }
                return processUpload(data)
            }
        }
```